# NextJS 13 Layouts are being combined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to create an admin section with a different layout than the one used in all the pages, but instead, I am seeing them combined.

This is my file structure:

- src/

  - app/

    - page.tsx
    - layout.tsx
    - admin/

      - page.tsx
      - layout.tsx

My intention is the `layout.tsx` on the `admin` folder should be different than the one on `src/app/layout.tsx` but instead, I am seeing both of them.

According to the [NextJS documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts), the `src/app/admin/layout.tsx` should be applied to the `src/app/admin/page.tsx` file automatically.

This is the code of the `/admin/layout.tsx` file:

```js
import AuthContext from '@/context/AuthContext'
import { Session } from 'next-auth'
import { headers } from 'next/headers'

async function getSession(cookie: string): Promise<Session> {
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/session`, {
    headers: {
      cookie,
    }
  })

  const session = await response.json()

  return Object.keys(session).length > 0 ? session : null
}

export const metadata = {
  title: 'My App',
  description: 'My App',
}

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const session = await getSession(headers().get('cookie') ?? '')
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <AuthContext session={session}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

What should I change to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

you're not utilizing the `getLayout` pattern properly

Define a getLayout function in your admin page

```
// src/app/admin/page.tsx
import AdminLayout from './layout'

export default function AdminPage() {
  // Your admin page component code
}

AdminPage.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return <AdminLayout>{page}</AdminLayout>
}
```

Similarly, define a getLayout function in your main app page:

```
// src/app/page.tsx
import AppLayout from './layout'

export default function AppPage() {
  // Your app page component code
}

AppPage.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return <AppLayout>{page}</AppLayout>
}
```

Then use the `getLayout` function

```
// pages/_app.js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)

  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: `getLayout()` has been replaced with [nested layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#nesting-layouts) on NextJS 13.

Answer (score -1):

Looking your code, you problem can be on the name of your nested layout `/admin/layout.tsx`

try change your
`export default async function RootLayout({`
to
`export default async function AdminLayout({`

Hopefully this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but nothing happened by changing the layout name.